# Smoothing out Android Game Loop

Tags: java, android, multithreading, game-loop

I am using the code below as a game loop for a simple Android game.  It works just fine, but every now and then there is a little hiccup in the game.  Everything freezes for a second and then jumps forward a bit farther than it should.  I did a good amount of reading up on game loops, but I'm still having a little trouble implementing a smooth loop. Would interpolating fix this?  How could I go about smoothing out the movement?

```
private final static int MAX_FPS = 30;
private final static int MAX_FRAME_SKIPS = 5;
private final static int FRAME_PERIOD = 1000 / MAX_FPS;

protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Log.d("MainTask", "starting game task");
    Canvas canvas;

    long begin;     // the time when the cycle began
    long delta;     // the time it took for the cycle to execute
    int sleep;      // ms to sleep if ahead
    int skipped;    // number of frames being skipped

    sleep = 0;

    while (running) {
        canvas = null;
        try {
            canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
                skipped = 0;

                gamePanel.update();
                gamePanel.draw(canvas);

                delta = System.currentTimeMillis() - begin;
                sleep = (int)(FRAME_PERIOD - delta);

                if (sleep > 0) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(sleep);
                    } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
                }

                while (sleep < 0 && skipped < MAX_FRAME_SKIPS) {
                    gamePanel.update();
                    sleep += FRAME_PERIOD;
                    skipped++;
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (canvas != null) surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
    Log.d("MainTask", "the task is complete");
    return null;
}
```

Comment: See: https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#loops

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've actually done most things correctly for this loop. There are a couple of potential pit falls I can see however

- You don't pass the frame time to your update method. This means your update method must assume a certain frame time. This is likely the cause of your jumps. You won't get constant frame rates if you are anywhere near the maximum performance of the machine, you just wont. And this broadly doesn't matter. If you miss a frame your brain fills in the missing frame and it looks fine. What absolutely does matter is a variable object *speed*. In this case a variable frame rate will cause a variable speed of your objects. Your update method should be:

  ```
  long previousFrameTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
  while (running){
      .....
      .....
      long currentTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
      long frameTime=currentTime-previousFrameTime
      previousFrameTime=currentTime
      gamePanel.update(frameTime/1000.0);  //I personally like my frametimes in seconds, hence /1000.0, but thats up to you
      .....
      .....
   }
  ```

  And all movement within the update should take that `frametime` into account when determining how far to move

To show how this matters, see the following two graphs. One with an assumed frame rate, the other with a measured frame rate. The dots represent actual rendered frames and the lines represent the interpolation thats happening within the viewers brain.

[image]

[image]

- You also hold on to the Canvas lock for a lot longer than nessissary. All the way through your update method and through the sleep as well you have a lock on the canvas. [This saps performance.](http://www.edu4java.com/en/androidgame/androidgame2.html) Get the lock just before you start rendering and release it as soon as you have finished

  ```
  gamePanel.update();
  canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
  gamePanel.draw(canvas);
  surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
  ```

Comment: Even if holding onto the canvas lock isn't causing the hiccup it is definitely worth fixing

Comment: All right the Canvas lock part makes sense.  By frameTime, do you mean my delta?  How exactly would I use that?  Would I need to recalculate that in the inner while loop as well?  Or just keep using the delta found above?

Comment: @user2694189 Your delta seems to be the processing time of the frame (ignoring any sleeping) - this isn't usually what delta is, usually delta is the frameTime. You want to record the time just before you make the update then next frame just before the update you get the time again and you get the difference between the two. This is the frameTime. Internal to the update method everything will have a velocity; you multiply the frameTime by the velocity to get how far it should move that frame

Comment: The same applys to any accelerations, accelerations are multiplied by the frametime to get the change in velocity. This is called euler integration. There are better integrations out there buy euler is usually sufficient for a game loop and is by far the simplest. In an ideal situation frameTime would equal FRAME_PERIOD but FRAME_PERIOD is the target and my frameTime is the true time you get (you may want to rename FRAME_PERIOD to TARGET_FRAME_PERIOD

Comment: To give an example. Imagine an object that has a velocity of 1m/s. Then we render that with a target FRAME_PERIOD of 0.1 seconds. Under the current code (with a variable frameRate) we might get the following results (time, position); (0,0) (0.1,0.1), (0.15,0.2), (0.28,0.3). You can see that all those data points are not only at a variable frame rate. The position is wrong. Where as by taking frame time into account you get (0,0), (0.15,0.15), (0.28,0.28). The frame rate is still wrong but the object is at least at the right place

Comment: Thank you that helped a LOT! I'm still experiencing very minor hiccups but it's definitely much better.  I think it's because now the animation is not constant. I'll look in to a way to fix that though. Thanks again

Comment: @user2694189 Glad to help. Good luck with your game!

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little too late but, here is how I implemented my game loop. With this, it can help you track your game's ticks(or updates) and frames per second.

```
long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
double nsPerTick = 1_000_000_000D/60D;
int frames = 0;
int ticks = 0;
long lastTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
double delta = 0;

while (mRunning) {
    Canvas canvas = null;
    long now = System.nanoTime();
    delta += (now-lastTime)/nsPerTick;
    lastTime = now;
    boolean shouldRender = false;

    while (delta >= 1) {
        ticks++;
        gameView.update();
        delta -= 1;
        shouldRender = true;
    }

    if (shouldRender) {
        frames++;
        canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        gameView.render(canvas);
        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }

    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimer >= 1000) {
        lastTimer += 1000;
        Log.d("FPS", "Ticks: " + ticks + ", Frames: " + frames);
        ticks = 0;
        frames = 0;
    }
}
```

This is based from a video tutorial by vanZeben meant for making Java game on pc, but it works on the Android game as well (at least for me).

Hope it helps.

Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VE7ezYCTPe4&list=PL8CAB66181A502179